# How to avoid issues with serialization in Spark when using methods in separate classes with AWS SDK?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aws-sdk

Inside my Spark (2.4) Scala script I am using methods from external classes written using AWS SDK Java. Most of these methods are simple operations on S3 like deleting a folder etc.:

```
import java.io.File
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.{ListObjectsV2Request, PutObjectRequest}
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._


object S3Utils {

  def deleteS3Folder(bucket: String, key: String) = {
    val s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build()
    val keyList = listFiles(bucket, key)
    if (keyList.nonEmpty) keyList.reverse.foreach(s3Client.deleteObject(bucket, _))
  }

  // other methods....
}
```

The problem is that inside some unrelated RDD operations, they get serialised to other executor nodes. That creates some problems like

```
Exception in task 25.1 in stage 16.0 (TID 370)
java.io.InvalidClassException: script.MyScript$$anonfun$1; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 0, local class serialVersionUID = -8902657938625313429
```

in a script like (I am using GeoSpark for the RDDs)

```
object MyScript {
   def main(sysArgs: Array[String]): Unit = {

     // firstDF and secondDF from spark.read.format("csv")...

     var firstRDD = Adapter.toSpatialRdd(firstDF, "geometry_point")
     var secondRDD = Adapter.toSpatialRdd(secondDF, "geometry_point")

     val joinResultPairRDD = JoinQuery.SpatialJoinQueryFlat(firstRDD, secondRDD, usingIndex, considerBoundaryIntersection).rdd.map { x =>
 val pcsFields = x._1.getUserData.asInstanceOf[String].split("\t")
 (x._2.toText, pcsFields(0), pcsFields(1), pcsFields(2))
}

     S3Utils.deleteS3Folder(....)
   }
}
```

I tried to change `S3Utils` from `object` to `class` to `trait` but nothing changed.
Any idea how to make callable external methods like this?

Comment: Can you show the actual implementation of `MyScript`? or rather a close approximation? The stacktrace seems to refer to a lambda that's defined somewhere which isn't visible in the code you wrote.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I have updated the script